# Is there a way to install Apptainer on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, dependencies

It is mentioned specifically on the [installation page](https://apptainer.org/docs/admin/latest/installation.html#installation) and in the error message, that appears if you try to launch the installer anyway, that:

> "The script works on current Red Hat Enterprise Linux-derived systems,
> Fedora, SUSE/OpenSUSE, Debian, and Ubuntu (except 18.04)."

And attempt to install it 'the Debian way' described on the page gives an error:

> "The following packages have unmet dependencies:apptainer : Depends: fuse-overlayfs but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Is there a way to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 at all (like by building it for 18.04 version)? I can not figure it out from the documentation. If "yes" - how do you do it?

Comment: "and Ubuntu (except 18.04).""  so no. Why doubt the creator of this software? If is was possible why would they not fix their installer? The more long term way to approach this is to  install  20.04 or even better 22.04.

Comment: The short answer is: "If I believed every word of the 'creator of... software' for the past 48 years of my work, I would be dead 10 times over."
Any more questions?

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04LTS becomes unsupported in April, 2023, you should consider upgrading to a supported release.

Comment: Maybe you can refer: https://github.com/apptainer/apptainer/blob/main/INSTALL.md
can install apptainer by youself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)